# -webkit-text-size-adjust isn't working the way I expect

Tags: css, iphone, ipad

I am trying to boost the font size of a website on iPhone and iPad Safari, without changing the size of the font in a desktop browser. I thought I found the answer with this (using SASS):

```
body
  font-size: 1em
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 110%
```

This actually does increase the size of the font on the iPad, but **reduces** the font size on iPhone. This doesn't seem right, so I must be misunderstanding something. Can anyone explain the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0">
```

Try adding this in the  section of your html. Some smart phones now zoom out to max to try fit in all the content. This hopefully will use default screen size for the particular devise.